# Will I get the "Manpower" achievement if my reactor gets upgraded in an event?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

I'm flying the *Zoltan* cruiser and I'm trying to unlock the **B** layout. The problem is that in the first sector my reactor has been upgraded in an event. Will I get the achievement if I reach sector 5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dug around in the FTL wikia's page for the [Manpower](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Manpower) achievement. Here is what is written, as of now:

> Trying to get this on FTL: Advanced Edition makes it much easier getting the achievement. Getting a backup battery allows having more energy for a short time and will not lock you out of this achievement. The Advanced Edition however also features events that can extend your generator capacity **which will not prevent you from getting the achievement**.

However, there was some point in time where that this wasn't completely known. It appears that [before April 6th](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Manpower?diff=next&oldid=20692), it was possible that those upgrades did affect the achievement or that is was assumed that it was. I didn't find any information about this on the patch lists, however as the information was corrected in the wiki it would be save to assume that someone verified that quest reactor upgrades would not affect the achievement.